# Java - passing an object as a parameter vs. using it's qualified name

Tags: java

I am writing a Java program where a method in one class needs to access a method of an object that is a member of another class. I can do this in at least two different ways, passing as a parameter, or directly accessing the object using the name of the class it is a member of. I find a lot of questions about pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value, but I can't find anything that addresses this scenario.
Here is some pseudo-code showing what I mean:

```
// class of object to pass
class MyPrefs {
  public String getPref(int i){
    String s = ... //some code to get a String indexed by i
    return s;
  }
}

// class where object is instantiated
class Main {
  protected static MyPrefs prefs = new MyPrefs();
}
```

Here are the two options I am looking at. In a third class, Toolbar, I can do either of these:

```
// pass as parameter
class Toolbar{
  public void applyPrefs(MyPrefs p){
    String s = p.getPref(1);
    ...
  }

//or use qualified name of object
class Toolbar{
  public void applyPrefs(){
   String s = Main.prefs.getPref(1);
   ...
  }
}
```

It works either way, what I would like to know is what are the merits or problems associated with each method, and if there is another way of doing this that I hadn't considered.

Comment: pass it in.  That is cleaner and less dependency on global variables.

Comment: `Main.prefs.getPref(1)` doesn't work since `prefs` is not a static field.

Comment: Oops.. just looked at my code again, prefs is protected static, will edit my question.

Comment: @Unmitigated I was about to post the same comment. Also, that would be an incorrect use of _static_ field in my opinion. Also, I think it is a bad idea to obtain a _pref_ by some sort of index unless you can guarantee that you would never be able to change its position; which I think it will be impossible.

Comment: Actually neither.  Law of Demeter is a good principle in this case. Pass the preference. The reason not to use the static value is to reduce `Toolbar`'s dependency on the internal structure of `MyPrefs`.  If you pass the preference itself, there's no dependency at all.

Comment: @hfontanez  I just used getting a string by index as an example of some possible use of the object, my real code doesn't do that (I'm using java.util.Properties key/value pairs). The method of passing the object is the thing I wanted to know about.

Comment: @GodJihyo Good!!! I was going to suggest using `java.util.Properties`.

Comment: @GodJihyo when you look at my posted answer, imagine I have a single class (maybe) called `PropUtils` that contain all of these methods. One thing to point out is that utility classes SHOULD NOT hold any data member (variables) and all its methods should be _static_. For example, `public static String getXYZProp(){...}`

Comment: @Gene What I'm doing is the main class creates an object of MyPrefs, and calls one of it's methods that loads properties from a file. When I need to get a property value MyPrefs has methods that return either an int, boolean, String, or Dimension based on a key value, something like this: 
Dimension iconSize = prefs.getPropertyDimension("toolbarIconSize");
So a method to update the toolbar might need to use a number of calls like this for different preferences, so it was either get all the values first and pass as a bunch of parameters, or pass the object and get the values through it.

Comment: @GodJihyo don't create objects of classes that only "do stuff". Those are normally called "utility classes" and for those, the best thing to do is to make all its methods _static_. Consider `java.lang.Math`. This class contain only _CONSTANT_ fields (no variables) and only contain method that "do stuff". Because there is no state change in the class (no variable data is stored in it), there is no reason to create instances of it. Instead, all its methods are _final_. This is what I typically do with utility classes and I believe this practice is widely adopted industry-wide.

Comment: And, about Gene`s point about **_Law of Demeter_**, I don't think this approach violates it. On the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this question doesn't get closed for being *opinion-based* because technically it is. So, I am not going to claim my answer is based on some undisputed best-practice, but I do believe it is generally accepted as the correct approach.

In my opinion, it would be either a variant of the first, and/or a combination of the two. For example:

```
public static String getProp(String prop) {
    // use java.util.Properties to retrieve the property.
}
```

This works well when your application has a single property file. In cases you have multiple property files, you need to override this method and pass the path to the correct file.

```
public static String getProp(String filename, String prop) {
    // use java.util.Properties to retrieve the property.
}
```

Where *filename* could be just the file name or the fully qualified name (with the path). I tend to keep all my property files in the same folder, so I "hard-code" the path and use that as the base location for my files, so most of the time when using this approach, I only need the actual file name.

I also have created utility methods to obtain specific properties where the name of the method implies what property I am obtaining. This is useful for people that are not too familiarized with the property keys.

```
public static String getXYZProp() {
    // use java.util.Properties to load the properties.
    return prop.getProperty("XYZ");
}
```

Alternatively, you should take advantage of the genetic method you created to do the same

```
public static String getXYZProp() {
    return getProp("XYZ");
}
```

Or even something like

```
public static String getXYZProp() {
    return getProp("someProps.properties", "XYZ");
}
```

It is OK to have multiple method that ultimately do the same thing. Think that some users will call the generic ones because they are more familiarized with the property keys while others will rely on method with names that help them figure out what properties they need to retrieve.

Comment: I will look into this further. Currently I am loading all of the properties when the program starts, and saving them on exit. I originally was doing it more like you are showing, getting and saving each property on the fly, but thought I could amortize all of the file reads/writes.

Comment: @GodJihyo there is a reason why I started my answer with _I hope this question doesn't get closed for being opinion-based_. But, there are some points I feel very strongly about. For example, encapsulating these into a single class and making the methods _static_. Overloading these methods to have one that can provide a property by name, or an exclusive method that can return that same property. Obviously, these decisions must be done with caution because what do you do if you have hundreds of these props? Some compromises have to be reached.